# Any robust DTD to XSD schema conversion tools?

Tags: xsd

Tools to convert a legacy DTD to XSD which are accurate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have used [trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html). It's free.

Answer (score 1):

Use Altova's XmlSpy.  It is pricey, but has a 30 day free trial.
http://www.altova.com/xmlspy.html

Comment: You open the DTD file. You then click the menu item "DTD/Schema". Select "Convert DTD/Schema..."

Comment: Convert DTD/Schema http://manual.altova.com/xmlspy/spyenterprise/index.html?convertdtdschema___.htm