# Apache Camel Validate with DTD

Tags: dtd, validation, apache-camel, jaxp

I am working on a POC with Apache Camel, I have to expose a WS through CXF, make some validation and transformation and call another WS.
I tried to use the validator but it seems that it's only work with xml schema...

```
<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
    <from uri="cxf:bean:sdmoWSKweb" />
    <to uri="log:input"/>
    <bean ref="CartWSExtractProcessor"/>
    <doTry>
        <to uri="validator:/dtd/configurator.dtd"/>
        <to uri="mock:valid"/>
        <doCatch>
            <exception>org.apache.camel.ValidationException</exception>
            <to uri="mock:invalid"/>
        </doCatch>
        <doFinally>
            <to uri="mock:finally"/>
        </doFinally>
    </doTry>
    <to uri="xslt:messageCopyItem.xslt"/>
    <setHeader headerName="operationName"><constant>copyItemMaster</constant></setHeader>
    <to uri="cxf:bean:qadCopyWeb?defaultOperationName=copyItemMaster"/> 
    <to uri="log:Output"/>
</route>
```

I tried to generate and xsd version of my dtd with the W3.org tool but the result is not valid.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Camel Validator](http://camel.apache.org/validation.html) does only work with XML/XSD or RelaxNG with the [Jing](http://camel.apache.org/jing.html) component.

Otherwise, you should trying another [DTD->XSD conversion tool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902631/any-robust-dtd-to-xsd-schema-conversion-tools) or just manually create an XSD version...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will try to solve my problem by using an xsd or whith a home made validation through a process.